# Is it possible to replicate some of C's macro functionality in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, logging, macros

I have to do a lot of logging for my current project, and I'm sick of writing `console.log('abc = ' + abc);` to do it, especially since `abc` can be very long.

I would really like to be able to write `logVar(abc);` and have it do the same thing.

This is trivial with a C macro with a stringizing operator, like

```
#define logVar(x) console.log(#x + ' = ' + x)
```

Is something like this possible in JS? My current attempt is

```
function logVar(x)
{
    console.log(Object.keys(x)[0] + ' = ' + x);
}
```

but this just prints `x = ...`, no matter what was passed.

Is there any way to do this without also having to pass the variable name? Cause at that point typing out `console.log(...` is probably just as good.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting this to output?

Comment: Sounds like you need a debugger, not more trivial logging (in both quantity and quality)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it's

```
function logVar(x)
{
    return console.log(
        Object.keys  (x)[0] + ' =', 
        Object.values(x)[0]);
}
```

you just have to call it with extra curly braces, like

```
logVar({value});
```

The reason I need this is that I'm working on a Figma plugin, and there's no debugging there on the Figma side, only logging. :(

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT concatenate in console since it can have really ugly results when the toString method is not what you want

for example

```js
const test = { "a":"A" }

console.log('test = ' + test); // test = [object Object]

// compared to 

console.log('test',test); //test { "a": "A" }

// or simpler

console.log({test});

const b = "My var";

console.log({b});

// Another example

const x = { "a":"A","b":"B" }

Object.entries(x).forEach(([key,val],i) => console.log(i,key,val))
```

Comment: This doesn't quite answer OP's question if you ask me...

Comment: Thanks for the hint on not concatenating in console!